# In SQL Server can I switch JSON output on and off via a parameter?

Tags: json, sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried the following code but I am getting a syntax error:

```
ORDER BY 
    Date ASC
IF (@Format = 'JSON')
    FOR JSON AUTO
```

Is it possible to do this? I am trying to control whether the output of this stored procedure is a table or a JSON document via an input parameter.

Comment: Only by repeating the query, or with dynamic SQL. You can't make a query change the shape of its result set based on a parameter -- that's true in general, not just for JSON vs. not. You can use a table variable or temp table to store the results if you don't feel like repeating the query, but this may have a performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

To dynamically alter your query you can use dynamic TSQL:

```
create table #tmp ([Date] datetime2)
insert into #tmp values
 ('2018-04-01')
,('2018-04-11')
,('2018-03-21')
,('2018-06-01')
,('2018-07-01')

declare @Format varchar(50)= 'JSON'
declare @sql   nvarchar(max)= ''

set @sql += ' select * from #tmp '
set @sql += ' ORDER BY '
set @sql += ' Date ASC'

if (@Format = 'JSON')
    set @sql += ' FOR JSON AUTO'

exec (@sql)
```

Result:

[image]

Now if you execute again the code changing the value of `@Format` variable:

```
declare @Format varchar(50)= 'other'
```

Result:

[image]

### Solution 2

Another solution is to call different stored procedures depending on the value of your variable:

```
if (@Format = 'JSON')
    exec dbo.My_SP_that_Returns_JSON
else
    exec dbo.My_SP_that_Returns_a_table
```